# Assigning Values to JSON Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, assign

This is what I'm trying to build via JavaScript in dot or [ ] notation:

```
var shoppingCart = { 
        'item1' : {
            'description' : 'This is item #1',
            'price' : 10,
            'quantity' : 1,
            'shipping' : 0,
            'total' : 10
        }
    };
```

Now if 'item1' is the variable name `itemName`.

This works:
`var shoppingCart = {};`
`shoppingCart[itemName] = itemName;`
`alert(shoppingCart.item1);`

Which returns `item1`

But this doesn't work:
`1 var shoppingCart = {};`
`2 shoppingCart[itemName]['description'] = 'This is Item #1';`

JS just dies at line 2, why? and how do I assign the description value to 'description'?

I would do it like this:

```
var shoppingCart = { 
        itemName : {
            'description' : description,
            'price' : price,
            'quantity' : quantity,
            'shipping' : shipping,
            'total' : total
        }
    };
```

...but it makes the key literally `itemName` instead of `item1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`shoppingCart[itemName]` doesn't exist.
You need to create it first:

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart[itemName] = { };
shoppingCart[itemName].description = 'This is Item #1';
```

Or, better yet:

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart[itemName] = { description: 'This is Item #1' };
```

Comment: Also `shoppingCart[itemName]['description']` is equivalent to `shoppingCart[itemName].description`.  You only need to access properties with `[]` when accessing them dynamically `obj[propNameString]` or when it contains illegal characters for dot notaton `obj['some-prop-name']`

Comment: Yes thnx, that's what I read everywhere, but the key is that `shoppingCart[itemName] = { };` I'm understanding objects more and more each day!

Answer (score 2):

In javascript objects do not auto-create on member access; you have to create the object first:

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart["item1"] = {}; // This creates the object
shoppingCart["item1"]["description"] = "This is item #1"; // add a member
```

Note you can of course also create the whole object at once with

```
shoppingCart[itemname] = { "description": description,
                           "price": price,
                           "quantity": quantity,
                           "shipping": shipping,
                           "total": total };
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because, in your second example, you're trying to index a blank object with a key that hasn't been set. The following will work...

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart[itemName] = {};
shoppingCart[itemName]['description'] = '...';
```

Because now shoppingCart[itemName] is actually an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, alternative solution:

```
var itemName = {};
itemName.description = 'This is Item #1';
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart.itemName = itemName;
```

or just

```
var shoppingCart = {};
shoppingCart.itemName = { description: 'This is Item #1' };
```